# AWS - Can't see Event Bridge Rule on Custom Bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, eventtrigger, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to target a Lambda function with an EventBridge Rule. When I go to set the Lambda trigger, the only rules I've ever been able to see were ones attached to the `default` bus.  Why can't my Lambda Trigger UI see rules when they are on my custom bus?

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciatd.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is UI limitation. You have to setup up the connection between your EB custom bus and your lambda function using `EventBridge` UI.